# What information do you keep about a project once it has been completed?

Tags: documentation, artifacts

Once a project reaches completion, which information do you keep/store for your records? Do you only keep a record of lessons learned, or do you also keep other project-specific information?

Comment: This question was asked from our private beta and only has 64 views as of 6/28/12. It *may* be possible to edit it to provide enough detail for there to be a solid answer, and then edit the answers to make them target the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- All metrics of estimation, and actuals
- A Complete traceable matrix from requirement document (blueprint) to User Acceptance Testing
- All official, approved documentation, and contract with vendors
- Lessons learned
- Initial budget, and final cost

I cannot think of anything, my last closing process was in April last year.

Comment: This list is very good. I would only add that a copy of the actual deliverables should also be saved.

Answer (score 2):

We keep everything.  Initial business requirements, functional scope documents, technical design documents, schedules, emails,... everything.  Each project in our company has its own sharepoint site where this stuff is stored so it's easy to find later.  You never know what piece of information is going to be useful when maintaining a system later, or if at some point down the line you just want to know "How did we do this on the last project?"

Comment: I think that OP is asking about a summary close-out report. Don't you do such a thing? In 5 years after the project is closed one has to review the entire repository in order to find some particular information?

Comment: @yegor256: I'm not aware of a summary close-out report, but I'm not a PM.  I've never seen one when looking through past projects, so if there's a report created, it isn't kept with the other project documents.

Answer (score 1):

Most documentation is probably not going to take up most space, so just store it on a file server, in the cloud, or in an archive.  There may be legal reasons for maintaining the documentation, so saving it will ensure you're covered.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on why you are keeping records.
If you do work in a regulated environment e.g. financial services, defense contractor, pharmaceuticals industry, your compliance department will determine what needs to be kept and what shouldn't be kept.

If you are keeping records to improve performance over time, keep the information related to the metrics you want to improve e.g. estimated vs actual time, change requests, lessons learned.

Another category of items to keep is the history of the work product produced as part of the project, e.g. the history of a brochure, previous designs for a website, etc.